# How can I fix this "convex" problem ? Is it just a matter of overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, model-evaluations, regularization, overfitting

I get some metrics on validation data while training a model , and in my case the they are :

> (0.25, 0.31, 0.46, 0.57, 0.65, 0.75, 0.77, 0.78, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85,
>   0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.82, 0.8, 0.8, 0.79, 0.78, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.75, 0.74, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73)

They can described like this :

[image]

In my view , the **ideal result** should be like :
[image]

**Is it a matter of overfitting** ?

Unfortunately , I tried few times to change the regular coefficients to avoid overfitting , and adjust learning rate coefficients to slow down , but it was still "convex" .

**How can I achieve the ideal result showed above** ?

Much appreciated if anyone would give me some constructive tips ?

Comment: What model are you training?

Comment: General Linear model , such as logic regression

Comment: Size of dataset? Type of validation? Still see same effect in k-fold cross-validation?

Comment: I used the "toy data" to validate my recommendation system with Spark , so I simplified the whole process . The size of dataset is small (15K) . I tried few tens of times to adjust coefficients , and almost each result came out to be "convex" .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are seeing is a classic case of overfitting.

You stated that you use a linear model such as logistic regression. To regularize these types of models, usually L1 and/or L2 regularization is applied. L1 regularization is simply $||W||_1$ and L2 is $||W||_2^2$ usually.

Another method is to alter the labels of the model in a specific way, which is a method of regularization I created (shameless plug). Here is the link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06693

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just do cross-validation between test-ds & validation-ds -- to select the moment in iterations, when overfitting starts in order to ignore all further iterations